# How to configure Neo4j Browser to use a custom REST endpoint?

Tags: neo4j

The server is running a custom REST endpoint configured using the following line

```
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/abc
```

in `neo4j-server.properties`.  REST is then working fine using `/db/abc`, but then the browser client (`http://$SERVERHOST:7474/browser`) stops working and displays the `Disconnected from Neo4j` message.  Packet sniffing indicates it is still trying to connect to `db/data`.  Clearing local web caches doesn't help.  Is there a way to point the browser client to use a custom endpoint?

[Sources](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/282e55de7c0a3ced084fbd79b4d0e6c64f63a8f3/community/browser/app/scripts/settings.coffee) indicate that `/db/data` is possibly hardcoded into the browser as part of client "Settings" (see line 23).  There is [supposedly](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/e2ca2134b4fa09d29ec12118a111db68f3bd2bc8) a way to reconfigure these settings using the `:config` command in the client, but the command bar is only available when the client is already connected to the server.

Is there a way to get this to work, or is it possibly a bug in the browser client?

Comment: you can change simple config properties in the browser by `:config maxFrames:100`. However I'm not aware of an easy way to change nested settings (as those for the URL paths). Another option is using a proxy with rewriting enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current option is to download source code of the browser and change what you need.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/browser